# Ruby on Rails - rspec Validation failed: Class must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm currently writing tests for my web application and I came across something out of my intelligence scope.

The context:
I am testing the "show" method of the UserController. However, User has a 1 to 1 relation with the class Face.

Here is the code testing the show method.

```
it "assigns the requested user as @user" do
   face = Face.create(:id => 1)
   user = User.create! valid_attributes
   get :show, params: {id: user.to_param}, session: valid_session
   expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
  end                                                                
end
```

`let(:valid_attributes) {
    { "lastName" => "lname", "firstName" => "fname", "face_id" => 1 }
  }`

When I run rspec here is the error in the console :

```
Failure/Error: user = User.create! valid_attributes

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Face must exist
```

How come Face doesn't exist If I created it?

Comment: can you post face and user models? Maybe Face needs something else besides id.

Comment: You hit it right in the middle. The problem was indeed in Face Class. It needed an additional property. I find it strange that it didn't log it in the console. Thanks linnal.

Comment: Why would you assign `id` yourself to Face object?

Comment: The class User and Face we're not really my classes name. I only used these for the example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that Face needed an additional attribute. Make sure you double check your models, because Rails won't tell you that the object creation failed. (This is what happened in my case.)

Comment: If this is correct, you should add the code snippet with the additional attribute and mark your own answer as accepted ;)